# Android Composable Recomposing Endlessly After Being Navigated To

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm making a simple app to learn Compose and its navigation API, and I'm running into an issue where a composable which represents a screen for a subfeature recomposes forever. The app has 2 features, so I've made multiple navigation graphs:

1. Base graph to navigate between feature A and feature B
2. Feature A graph to navigate between its subfeatures
3. Feature B graph to navigate between its subfeatures

I've created these nested graphs by following the [recommended approach](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nested-nav) to make extension functions for each graph.

The problem I have is for feature A, which is what shows when you open the app. In my `MainActivity#onCreate`, I create the base navigation graph with feature A's home screen as its start destination:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AppGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "home",
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        homeGraph(navController)
        featureAGraph(navController)
        featureBGraph(navController)
    }
}
```

`HomeGraph` is constructed as such:

```kotlin
fun NavGraphBuilder.homeGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    navigation(startDestination = FeatureA.route, route = "home") {
        composable(FeatureA.route) {
            FeatureAHome(navController)
        }
        composable(FeatureB.route) {
            FeatureBHome(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

Feature A's "home" composable creates a list of buttons that when clicked on will navigate to a subfeature screen. When I click on a button, the subfeature's home composable is the one that recomposes endlessly. I navigate to this composable by setting an `onClick` action on the buttons to call the view model, which emits flow with the route that should be navigated to. I observe this flow as such:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FeatureARoute(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    val viewModel: FeatureAHomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val navigationState = viewModel.navigationRoute.collectAsStateWithLifecycle("")
    val route = navigationState.value

    if (route.isNotEmpty()) {
        navController.navigate(route)
    }
}
```

Feature A's navigation graph looks like this:

```kotlin
fun NavGraphBuilder.featureAGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    navigation(startDestination = "feature_A_home", route = "feature_A") {
        composable(SubfeatureA.route) { 
            SubfeatureAHome(navController) 
        }
        composable(SubfeatureB.route) { 
            SubfeatureBHome(navController) 
        }
    }
}
```

`SubfeatureAHome` starts off by showing a progress bar which should go away after data is retrieved from a Room database, but this is where I'm having the problem. The progress bar is redrawn repeatedly and never displays properly, which means this composable is recomposing endlessly. Even if I remove the code to retrieve the data from the database and only show the progress bar, I still have the issue:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SubfeatureAHome(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    CircularProgressIndicator(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
    )
}
```

From my understanding, a composable should only recompose when one of its arguments changes, or a state that it's observing changes. Neither is happening here, so I don't know why it keeps recomposing. If I put log statements in `FeatureARoute` and `SubfeatureAHome`, I repeatedly get messages about navigating to subfeature A:

```
Navigating to subfeature A home
Navigating to subfeature A home
Recomposing subfeature A home
Navigating to subfeature A home
Recomposing subfeature A home
Navigating to subfeature A home
Recomposing subfeature A home
Navigating to subfeature A home
Recomposing subfeature A home
// and so on
```

I've verified that the `navigationRoute` which is being observed isn't changing after clicking the button, so I don't know why this composable keeps getting navigated to. And even if it's repeatedly navigated to, isn't its argument (`navHostController`) the same each time, so shouldn't it not recompose?

If I modify `featureAGraph` and set its start destination as `subfeature_A_home`, the composable loads just fine, so it seems to be an issue with how I've set up the navigation graph. If anyone could help me understand where I went wrong, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Recomposition due to the cross fade animation between screens is expected. You should never, ever be calling `navigate` as part of composition - please read the page on [side-effects](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects) and specifically look at `LaunchedEffect`.

Comment: I understand recomposition due to animations will occur, but my composable is recomposing forever and the UI is not being displayed because it gets redrawn endlessly. How would `LaunchedEffect` help me here? It's only to call suspend functions within composables and I'm not calling any suspend functions.

Comment: You're calling navigate on every frame, so you're navigating endlessly to new instances of the next screen, thus restarting cross fades to new screens over and over again. `LaunchedEffect` is also used for running something only once, suspending or not.

Comment: I see. I ended up following [this codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-navigation?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-navigation#0) which explained that you should call `navigate` within the `composable()` function by passing in lambdas to react to specific actions, and now it works as expected.